# service calling another service, implementation question

Tags: angular

I believe I am doing something wrong, cause I probably don't exactly know what I am doing ->

I have a module with 5 services that I want only in that module.

```
  providers: [
    {provide: SYNCH_MAP_TOKEN, useFactory: SynchMapFactory },
    {provide: SYNCH_WAYPOINT_TOKEN, useFactory: SynchWaypointFactory },
    forwardRef(() => NavigationWaypointSyncherService),
    forwardRef(() => NavigationMapSyncherService),
    NavigationControllerService
]
```

the first 2 are made from factory, because I want 2 different instance of the same service, with 2 different type :

```
export const SYNCH_MAP_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<SynchronizatorService<SynchMapElement, SynchMapElementSubject>>('Token for SynchMap');
export const SYNCH_WAYPOINT_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<SynchronizatorService<SynchWaypointElement, SynchWaypointElementSubject>>('Token for SynchWaypoint');

export const SynchMapFactory = () => new SynchronizatorService<SynchMapElement, SynchMapElementSubject>();
export const SynchWaypointFactory = () => new SynchronizatorService<SynchWaypointElement, SynchWaypointElementSubject>();
```

The 2 other, are forwardRef, because they need the 2 token instacied service

```
  constructor(@Inject(SYNCH_WAYPOINT_TOKEN) synchService: SynchronizatorService<SynchWaypointElement, SynchWaypointElementSubject>,
              private navigationControllerService: NavigationControllerService) {
```

but those 2 service are able to get a ref of my 5th service `NavigationControllerService`.

Now, I also want NavigationControllerService to get the ref of `NavigationWaypointSyncherService` and `NavigationMapSyncherService`

but this time, if I do

```
constructor(public waypointSyncherService: NavigationWaypointSyncherService)
```

I get "can't  resolve all param for `NavigationControllerService`

I believe I am not able to get a ref from another service inside a service, but it works with the 2 with forwardRef, and not the one without ?

I was about to call a "init" function in `NavigationControllerService` where i store the ref of my 2 other services, but is that implementation ok ?